# How to serializer an ImageField from another model in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, imagefield

I know there are many similar questions but none of them solves my problem.

I have a simple topic that has an image field, a topic title, a topic content, a topic slug and etc.

That topic is associated with a user using the foreignkey. The serializer is doing fine until the

serializer for the image field was added.

serializers.py

```
class TopicDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    topic_author = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_topic_author')
    topic_author_picture = serializers.SerializerMethodField(
        'get_topic_author_picture')

    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ['id', 'topic_title', 'topic_content', 'created_date',
                  'topic_slug', 'thread_title', 'topic_author', 'topic_author_picture', ]

    def get_topic_author_picture(self, topic):
        return topic.owner.profile_picture

    def get_topic_author(self, topic):
        return topic.owner.username
```

The output in the console when I request the data from frontend:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte`

Ain't I just storing the path to the Image rather than the image itself? I mean I have a user profile serializer which sends information to the requested user and it includes an image. But it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [**`FieldFile.url`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url) as

```
def get_topic_author_picture(self, topic):
    return topic.owner.profile_picture.url
```